# NodeJS/Express share function between multiple routes files

Tags: node.js, function, express, server-side

I have an NodeJS/Express app with several route files in /routes folder. I would like to be able to call a function on a server side i.e. myfunction.js from any of route files. What is the best way to set it up. 
As of now, i have myfunction.js duplicated in each of route files.

Comment: require function in all  route ??

Comment: You mean something like `const myFunction = require('./utils/myfunction.js')`? Create a separate file for your utility function and import it wherever you need it - https://stackabuse.com/how-to-use-module-exports-in-node-js/

Comment: @goto1. Yep somthink like that. Thank You.

Comment: @goto1. That's seems like exactly what I need. Thank You